# Integration: $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(at)}{2\cosh 2\pi t-1} \text{ d}t$

Tags: integration, contour-integration

I am trying to calculate the following integral: $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(at)}{2\cosh 2\pi t-1} \text{ d}t$$

The inspiration for it was that a similar integral carries a closed form:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin at}{e^{2\pi t}-1}\text{ d}t=\frac{1}{4}\coth \frac{a}{2}-\frac{1}{2a}$$

> I was wondering how exactly to go about solving the topmost integral.

Comment: [Answer](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ntVWQ.png).

Comment: @Lucian, your input/output looks like Mathematica code. When I enter the integral in Mathematica, I get output in terms of hypergeometric functions (and a bit more complicated expression all in all). Did you do some simplifications by hand? Or did you let Mathematica do some simplifications? By the way, if one changes the $2$ in front of cosh into a $1$, the integral has a slightly simpler look...

Comment: @mickep: `FunctionExpand[...]` and `FullSimplify[...]`.